Merge a multi index of year, then month into one index year-month
My code so far
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from scipy.stats import shapiro
import scipy.stats as stats


ios = pd.read_csv('iOS.csv')

ios.replace(',','', regex=True, inplace=True)

ios = ios.astype({'Total Impressions': int, 'App Referrer Impressions': int, 'Browse Impressions': int,
                  'Search Impressions': int, 'Total Installs': int, 'App Referrer Installs': int,
                  'Browse Installs': int, 'Search Installs': int, 'CVR': float, 'App Referrer CVR': float,
                  'Browse CVR': float, 'Search CVR': float})

ios['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ios['Date'])


ios = ios.groupby(
    [
        ios['Date'].dt.year,
        ios['Date'].dt.month
    ]
).mean()

This results in a data frame with a multi-index. The first index is Year, and the second index is Month. I'd like to merge these indices into a single Year-Month date object, so I can make a line-lot where each x tick is a month in a specific year.

Use month periods if need datetimelike object YYYY-MM by Series.dt.to_period:
ios = ios.groupby(
    [
        ios['Date'].dt.to_period('M')
    ]
).mean()

Alternative for remove Date column is use DataFrame.pop:
ios = ios.groupby(
    [
        ios.pop('Date').dt.to_period('M')
    ]
).mean()

Or is possible use end of month instead in DataFrame.resample, output format is YYYY-MM-DD:
 ios = ios.resample('ME', on='Date').mean()

Last solution is use Series.dt.strftime, but datetimelike object is lost:
ios = ios.groupby(
    [
        ios['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
    ]
).mean()


Stunning, thank you.

@m.lekk Thais answer looks correct to me. If you agree, you should accept it as correct.
